# How to calculate the Knudsen number?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, chemical-engineering, experimental-physics

when calculating the Knudsen number:
$$ Kn=\frac{\lambda_{mf}}{L} $$
Where $\lambda_{mf}$ is the mean free path of a molecule, and $L$ is the characteristic length. How is the characteristic length determined in a "realistic" scenario? Would it be based on a specific parameter, or more like an order of magnitude?
Thanks!

Comment: So which reference did this come from? what is a molecular?

Comment: @SolarMike, apologies, molecular is meant to be molecule. As for reference, I'm not sure I understand what you mean, I have seen Kn defined as such everywhere.

Comment: These dimensionless numbers are often applied in thermal and mass transport analyses, so I'd look to define the characteristic length based on the dimension that the mass/heat transfer is being considered.